# can you damage a machine by rebooting too often?

Tags: reboot

Can you damage a computer by rebooting too often?  I'm planning to leave a machine automatically rebooting every 30 mins (scheduled shutdown task).  It's a standard dell x86 running XP.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering why, its not a good reason - http://serverfault.com/questions/117229/windows-automatically-restore-flakey-network-connection/117265#117265

Comment: i've added an answer (and vbscript) over there to hopefully cut down on the number of reboots by NOT rebooting if the connection is alive.

Comment: @bill thank you!  I'll leave this question open out of academic interest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Booting up is pretty harsh on many of the components, but they're resilient enough that it's not really relevant anymore in this day-and-age.

Comment: I would dare give the same advice even in 1990. or round that time, also.

Comment: Warm reboots? Not so bad (maybe lots of hard disk wear). Cold starts? Much more troublesome.

Answer (score 2):

If your power supply is a bit dodgy constant reboots might damage some components.  I've certainly had a dodgy PSU fritz motherboards on reboot before.